# How to know if IEEE 1394 (FireWire) is connected to my Windows 7?

Tags: windows, wmi, firewire

My computer has an IEEE 1394 (FireWire) input. 
How programmatically to know if 1394 is connected to my Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Win32_1394ControllerDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class.